# How to display php data in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

This is the PHP code:

```
$file = fopen("data.txt","r");
$datastring = fread($file, filesize("data.txt"));

//gzcompress a string
$compressed   = gzdeflate($datastring, 9);
echo $compressed."<br />";
//gzuncompress a string
$uncompressed = gzinflate($compressed);
echo $uncompressed."<br />";
echo json_encode($compressed);
```

I want to a write a javascript function in another file which when clicked(`onClick`) gets this php data and appends to a new `div`. It should display both the '`compressed`' and '`uncompressed`' variables. How can I do this? Thanks for the help.

The sample html/script. Not sure if its correct.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Compress</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getData()
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'comp.php', true);

    request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        showData(data);
    }
};

request.send();

}

function showData(msg)
{
    div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = msg;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="GET FILE" onclick="getData()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

How to make it work from here?

Comment: How is the JavaScript going to interact with this?  Are you going to make an AJAX request to this PHP resource?  Is this PHP going to echo data to the page and the JavaScript will use that data?  Something else?

Comment: When I use onClick on the javascript function, the php should echo the value of these variables.

Comment: It sounds like what you're asking is how to use AJAX.  That's a bit broad, but the search term you're looking for is something like "PHP AJAX tutorial" or "PHP AJAX example".  There are a variety of examples with or without jQuery.